# CoreData in a tableCell Causes a stutter/lag IOS/xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

Good Morning.

I have a problem when I run my app on my device, it lags/stutters when I scroll in the main tableView.

I've narrowed the problem down to a call to core data from inside my tableCell

--In cell for row at indexPath
person is a custom class and contact manager is my file with all my calls to core data and manipulating data

```
    person.contactSelected = [contactManager checkContactSelectedStatus:person];
```

--In my contactManager file the call goes to this function.

and just updates the contacts selected status (when the user presses a button to change from being allowed in the call or not in the call)

```
-(NSNumber *) checkContactSelectedStatus:(ContactPerson *)person{

SWNAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *req =[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

[req setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *pred =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(recordID like %@)",[person.recordID stringValue]];

[req setPredicate:pred];

NSError *error;

NSManagedObject *checkStatus = [[context executeFetchRequest:req error:&error] objectAtIndex:0];

person.contactSelected = [checkStatus valueForKey:@"isSelected"];

return person.contactSelected;}
```

Is there an easy way to throw this into a Queue?  I have read and tried to figure out how to send a NSManagedObject to queues, but when I create a child of the Parent MoC, It can not find the Entity "Contact".  I don't know if there is a simpler way to do it or not!?

Thanks for your time, and
WhatWasIThinking!?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is really inefficient code. The fetch has to be done multiple times, i.e. for each cell as it becomes visible.

You should instead use an `NSFetchedResultsController` which is especially designed to work with table views. It will decide the appropriate number of trips to the store for fetches and optimize for speed and memory footprint.

Also, you will most likely use significantly less code.

Besides, a predicate string like `recordID like %@` does not make much sense. If you are using IDs they should be unique so you can index them and look them up really fast. `LIKE`, just like string functions such as `CONTAINS` are very slow in comparison.